# Unable to connect to mysql DB through my HA Proxy Servers [Keepalived is used for Virtual IP-VIP]

Tags: mysql, mariadb, haproxy

I have my HAProxy running on `VIP:192.168.61.32`, also I've checked `netstat -tulnp|grep 3306`

```
 tcp        0      0 192.168.61.32:3306      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7895/haproxy
```

But when I run `mysql -h 192.168.61.32 -u root -p`:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

My Backend Mysql Nodes are at `192.168.61.33 & 192.168.61.34`, I'm able to Connect to them directly using  `mysql -h 192.168.61.33 -u root -p`

```
 mysql -h 192.168.61.34 -u root -p
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check if there are any connection errors between haproxy and mysql. If you run `systemctl status haproxy` or `tail /var/log/haproxy-traffic.log`, you may find the error similar to the one below

> Server mysql_farm/galera03 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code:
> 0, info: "Host 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is blocked because of many connection
> errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'", check duration: 0ms. 2
> active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0
> remaining in queue.t

In that case you need to run the command `mysqladmin flush-hosts` to clear blocked IPs from mysqld so that haproxy can connect again.

You may need to run the command as `mysqladmin -uroot -p flush-hosts`

See docs below for further reference in how to resolve the error.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/host-cache.html#blocked-host

Answer (score 0):

I think you can recheck bind-address and Edit the global my.ini file, in the [mysqld] section:

[mysqld]

## -- various other settings

```
port = 3306
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Save this file, and then restart service mysql with command:

```
service mysql restart
```

Edit

To grant a user access from a remote IP, run this command from the mysql> shell when logged in with the MySQL root user:

```
GRANT ALL on somedb.* to someuser@192.168.61.32 identified by 'somepassword';
```

If you want to grant access to someuser from any remote IP:

```
GRANT ALL on somedb.* to someuser@% identified by 'somepassword';
```

After those steps, make sure to restart the MySQL server so it will read the changes in the configuration.